# How can I write a templated function for std::variant?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, variant

here is the problem:

```
std::queue<std::variant<std::vector<int>>, std::string>> data;

void write() {
    //if vector<int>
    toPut=data.front()[0];
    //if std::string
    toPut=data.front().data()

    asyncFunction(toPut, [](){
       ..whole bunch of code in lambda
    });
}
```

I need to call a different member function dependent on the data type stored in the actual variant? I could write a function and check the index of the variant I guess?

Can I also do it at compile time using std::visit? I would like to write a templated lambda function that will call the correct function member depending on the actual type passed to the lambda? Ideally with a constexpr if and type_traits without passing multiple overloads to std::visit.

something like this:

```
std::visit([](auto& variant) {
   if constexpr(std::is_same<variant, std::string>::value) {
      return variant.data(); 
   } else {
     return variant[0];
   }
}, data.front());
```

So its bascially like polymorphism but at compile-time without providing multiple overloads for lambda instead using type_traits.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass in an overload set? It's not much more verbose than the `if-constexpr` you'd like to write.

Comment: yes, you are right. But now that I have been thinking about it, I would like to solve it without using overloads. I want to train with templates a bit. So, is it doable?

Comment: It's probably doable, but if you don't want to use overloads then why do you want to use `std::visit` at all? Your constraints seem rather strange (and also artificial, but that's fine).

Comment: well, can you do it even without std::visit?

Comment: please do not put a `?` after every sentence.

Comment: Yes you can do it without visit: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative